# How to create Param to filter data EQUAL to a value or NOT EQUAL to the same value

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm working on a simple report and my dataset looks like this:

| ID | Date | Attribute | Customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2022-03/15 | NULL | Cust_B |
| 144529 | 2022-05/20 | 239 | Cust_A |
| 11223 | 2022-05/20 | NULL | Cust_C |
| 168236 | 2022-05/20 | 66 | Cust_A |

I would like to create a Parameter to manage rows based on the *Attribute* column, so that I can:

- select **only** rows with Attribute **=** 239
- select **only** rows with Attribute **!=** 239
- select **all** rows

The *Attribute* Column is an INT column and could assume 20 different values (every number is a code for a specific type of attribute)

is it possible to do so with only a single Parameter?

I **can** work on the query on SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this using a single parameter, but it's not that intuitive.

Firstly, you'll want a query like the following. As there are 3 options, I implicitly define the parameter as a `bit`:

```sql
SELECT {Column List}
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE (@ParameterName = 1 AND YT.Attribute = 239)
   OR (@ParameterName = 0 AND YT.Attribute != 239)
   OR (@ParameterName IS NULL)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Then, in SSRS you'll want to parameter as a boolean and allow `NULL` values.

In the Available Values pane of the parameters, you then need to define the 3 available values, which you'll want to be something like the following:
true - Attribute = 239
false - Attribute != 239
NULL - All Rows

*Note, I assume you literally mean `!= 239`, which means that rows where `Attribute` has the value `NULL` will be excluded, as `NULL != 239` evaluates to UNKNOWN.*

Comment: IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM can be used in SQL 2022 and SQL Azure to handle this issue, in addition to the above.